# Erro no Handler.obtainMessage

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estou desenvolvendo um app que utiliza a conexão Bluetooth, mas estou encontrado um problema que não estou conseguindo solucionar.
Eu estou seguindo a orientação deste link para tal https://developer.android.com/guide/top ... tooth.html.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
Handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

A palavra "**Handler**" e **"MESSAGE_READ"** está dando erro e não sei como fazer, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Poste a mensagem de erro, se não fica dificil saber o problema

Comment: A message_read é uma constante.. provavelmente deve-se declarar na sua classe, handler você tem que criar a instancia antes. Ex: Handler mHandler = new Handler() e implementar o Handler e fazer a chamada com  mHandler.obtainMessage(...)